# WPF menu item template problem

Tags: wpf

I've written a template for a menuItem within which i've a Toggle button which in turn has a template. In the template of the button i provide different visual effects for different visual states of the button by changing the opacities of different borders. Now say when the menuItem is clicked, the clicked effect on the action button is shown. but when i hover over that menuItem again i expect to have the same highlighted effect even on the checked state of the toggle button. But the highlighted effect is applied to the whole menuitem except this toggle button just because the hover event is not propagated to the button.

Wanted to attach the image to make the problem clear but since I am new to this I am not allowed to do so.

How can i set the opacity of the border which gives the clicked effect to 0 when the menuItem is highlighted?!

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="stackPanel" Background="{StaticResource DataLayerPanelBackGroundColorBrush}" >
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="../Themes/Framework.xaml"/>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Border x:Name="backgroundMouseOverVisual2" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,3,0,3"  
                                    Background="{StaticResource ActionButtonMouseOverBackgroundColorBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                <local:ActionButton DataContext="{TemplateBinding Tag}" x:Name="actionButton" Background="White"
                    MultiActionIdent="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ActionToIdentConverter}}"       
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Style="{StaticResource MultiActionMenuItemActionButtonStyle}" Margin="0" 
                    />
            </Grid>
            <StackPanel x:Name="contentStackPanel" Background="{StaticResource DataLayerPanelBackGroundColorBrush}" Grid.Column="1">
                <ContentPresenter
                    TextElement.Foreground="{StaticResource MenuTextColorBrush}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                Name="HeaderHost"
                ContentSource="Header"
                RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                Width="Auto"
                Margin="10,4,35,4" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="InputGestureText"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
                DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
        </Grid>
        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="0.5" Margin="1,1,1,1" Padding="2,2,2,2" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{x:Null}" Opacity="0"/>
    </Grid>
```

And below is the ToggleButton template which is named as actionButton in the above template:

Comment: Something like when the IsHighlighted property of the menuItem is set to true the opacity value of the border within the control template of the toggle button should be set to 0. How can i do it??

Comment: Ummmm, purely from memory, doesn't the WPF MenuItem have some built-in toggling capability? Something like IsChecked? Either way, the MenuItem I think already includes a button in its template, and all sort of trickery is needed to pass events between two superimposed buttons. Making the contents of the MenuItem something else would simplify things, I bet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Style Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.triggers.aspx) to change a style based on a different state.

Sample snippet:

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```